# MySQL fill empty dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been trying to get my head around this for a time now and can't find a solution: I am querying for time-entries with a result like this:

```
2015-02-10: 13
2015-02-11: 16
2015-02-13: 11
```

As you can see I am missing two days in the array because there are no entries for these days. My google-fu brought me some solutions for this problem but none seem to work for my specific code:

```
SELECT
    DATE(time_entries.start) AS date,
    COUNT(time_entries.id) AS entries,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 4 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) ELSE 0 END) AS me,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 3 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) ELSE 0 END) AS ph
    FROM time_entries
    LEFT JOIN calendar_table
    ON time_entries.start=calendar_table.dt
    WHERE start BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
```

I created the calendar_table with this help: https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Please help!
Best,
Chris

Comment: Could you post the tables definition? The column names and types only.

Answer (score 0):

Try with right join. Your query is using your time_entries records to match the calendar table, and finds nothing because they're not there.

By using right join, you'll use calendar_table records first.

```
SELECT
    DATE(time_entries.start) AS date,
    COUNT(time_entries.id) AS entries,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 4 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) ELSE 0 END) AS me,
    SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 3 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, end) ELSE 0 END) AS ph
    FROM time_entries
    RIGHT JOIN calendar_table
    ON time_entries.start=calendar_table.dt
    WHERE start BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. When I simply exchange my LEFT JOIN with RIGHT JOIN, I receive some few, random entries.